# String Date not converting to type date despite datevalue

Tags: excel, date, datetime

I have a datetime column(A column). I converted that to date(B column) using below formula. Column A by the way is actual datetime

```
 =MONTH(a2) & "/" & DAY(a2) & "/" & YEAR(a2)
```

Now the issue is that this column of date is getting displayed as string, so I changed the column type to Short date, nothing happened (it is still string, I am unable to subtract this date from another date).

Also on using below formula to change the type of date to date type:

```
= Datevalue(b2)
```

After using datevalue some of the dates are changed as date type ( I am able to subtract the final date from another date basically) but some dates are still not converted to dates.

What to do ?

Comment: Just use `=INT(A2)` and format as date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, I am considering that the date time format in column A is not string and actual date time so you can simply use:

`=INT(A2)`

and then apply desired cell formatting using standard date formatting options.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an example of the datetime value?

I tried a mock version and had no problem. But perhaps I misunderstand what your problem is.

[image]